# Почему компилятор не может автоматически реализовать сравнение объектов?

Tags: .net

Компилятор достаточно умный и многие вещи способен генерить автоматически. Так почему он не может автоматически сгенерировать сравнение экземпляров класса не только по ссылке? Имхо в 99% случаев уникальность класса- это сумма всех полей, остальной 1% это экзотика. Не могу представить случаев, когда бы для сравнения равенства классов использовалось n полей из m. Так собственно, почему компилятор сам это не сгенерировать?

Comment: это не нужно!!!

Comment: *Не могу представить случаев...* Часто при работе с БД достаточно сравнения первичного ключа.

Comment: @Grundy ну в яваскрипте это сделано, если ты об этом, что ведёт к непредсказуемому результату временами, но если сделали бы умно, то имхо чётко было

Comment: @iluxa1810, что сделано в яваскрипте?

Comment: @Nofate но верно ли это с идеологической точки зрения? Когда я вызываю метод сравнения, то ожидаю, что будет глубокое сравнение.

Comment: @iluxa1810 так это какие-то ваши внутренние ожидания. Инженер читает спеку и ожидает согласно спеке )

Comment: Для сравнения - компилятор Rust генерировать умеет, например

Comment: Еще пример: enum-ы. Нет смысла сравнивать их поля детально. Еще пример: объекты с вычисляемыми полями. В целом сравнивать нужно тот набор полей, который *однозначно* идентифицирует объект.

Comment: @Nofate, ИМХО от стандартного equals, если он переопределено, ожидаешь именно глубокое сравнение. Иначе, будет вызываать вопросы, что вы сравниваете 2 записи из БД между собой, ID=ID=> объекты равны, а потом смотришь с недоумением, как оно может быть равно если другие значение не равны.=) Т.е не интуитивно понятно.

Comment: В доке на .NET есть абзац *[The following statements must be true for all implementations of the Equals(Object) method.](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.object.equals?view=netframework-4.7.2)*, перечисляющий, что вы должны ожидать от Equals.

Comment: Кстати граф объектов может быть зациклен, в таком случае глубокое сравнение, безусловно сгенерированное компилятором, может привести к StackOverflow.

Comment: @Nofate, вот это хороший довод.

Answer (score 2):

Может, но не хочет. Для структур это уже и так реализовано, сравнение по умолчанию осуществляется путем сравнения значений всех полей. Однако классы считаются чуть более сложными, чем структуры, и сравнение их таким образом не всегда имеет смысл:

1. Класс может содержать ссылку на объект того же класса (узел дерева, например). Как это будет работать? Хотели сравнить узлы, получаем вместо этого сравнение целых веток дерева?
2. Класс может содержать поля, характеризующие его текущее состояние, но незначительные для его логической идентификации. Например, при сравнении двух автомобилей нет смысла сравнивать уровень бензина, температуру в салоне и т.п. Достаточно сравнить номер.

Поэтому предполагается, что типы, для которых равенство определяется равенством всех полей, должны быть структурами, а классы должны переопределять Equals, реализуя нормальное сравнение по правилам предметной области.